# Get the last element of a list in f#

Tags: .net, list, function, f#, reverse

I want to get the last element of a list and my logic is to reverse the list and to get its head:

```
module Program1 = 

    let last list =
        let newList=List.rev list;
        List.head newList;
        newList 

    let mainP1()=
        let list= [ 1; 2; 3] 
        printfn "Ultimul element al listei %A este %A" list (last list )
```

but it gives me this error

```
Error       Type mismatch. Expecting a
    unit list    
but given a
    int list    
The type 'unit' does not match the type 'int'
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: There's a built-in function for that: `List.last`. Is this homework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is quite a lot to unpack here.

**First**, your function is not returning what you want it to return. See that last line there, the one that says `newList`? That's your function's return value. The last line of the function body is its return value. So you're returning the reversed list, not the last element.

**Second**, since you're not returning the result of the `List.head` call, you're *ignoring* it. Not doing anything with that result. Ignoring. And F# compiler tries to help you here: if you're ignoring a value, it means you're doing something wrong, and F# will complain (issue a warning) if you do that.

But there is one exception to that rule: you can ignore a value of type `unit`. The logic goes, if you've got a value of type `unit`, you must have obtained it as a result of producing a side-effect. Because if there was no side effect, and there is no resulting value (`unit` means "no value"), then what was the point?

So, the compiler thinks like this: if you've ignored a value, then that value must be of type `unit`. And since `List.head newList` is of type `unit`, then `newList` must be of type `unit list`. And therefore, `list` must be of type `unit list`. And therefore, your function is of type `unit list -> unit list` (i.e. it takes a `unit list` as parameter and returns another `unit list` as result).

And since you're trying to pass an `int list` into a function that takes a `unit list`, the compiler can't stand it: `Expecting a unit list but given a int list`.

**And finally**, reversing the list just to get at its last value is so very wasteful! You're reallocating a whole lot of memory that you don't really need. A less wasteful way to achieve this is via the use of recursion. Think about it this way: the last element of a one-element list is that one element, and the last element of a longer list is the last element of its tail. We can write that straight in F#:

```
let rec last list =
  match list with
  | [x] -> x   // The last element of one-element list is the one element
  | _::tail -> last tail   // The last element of a longer list is the last element of its tail
  | _ -> failwith "Empty list"   // Otherwise fail
```

Plus, there is a ready-made function `List.last` that you can just use (unless this is homework, in which case you should mention that in the question).

```
let mainP1()=
  let list= [ 1; 2; 3] 
  printfn "Ultimul element al listei %A este %A" list (List.last list)
```

Beware, though, that there may not be a last element in the list - if the list is empty. In this case, `List.last` (as well as `List.head`) will crash with an exception, which is generally not a good idea. If you need to handle the empty-list case, look at `List.tryLast` instead:

```
let mainP1()=
  let list= [1; 2; 3] 
  match List.tryLast list with
  | Some x -> printfn "Ultimul element al listei %A este %A" list x
  | None -> printfn "Lista %A este goală" list
```

Comment: An immutable linked list aka `FSharp.Collections.List<'T>` is not that efficient for random access: the whole list has to be traversed, hence O(n). `List.rev` isn't better or worse than that.

Comment: @kaefer you're right. For some reason I was under the impression that F# cheated there for performance, [the way it does with List.map](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L238) for example, but apparently that is not the case. I will remove this point from the answer.